# Does the halogenation of an alkane also produce haloalkanes of a longer chain length?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

Take a typical halogenation of an alkane reaction (the bromination of methane).

$$\ce{Br_2->Br· + Br· (in the presence of UV light)} $$

$$\ce{Br· + CH4->·CH3 + HBr} $$

One of the possible termination reactions is

$$\ce{·CH3 + ·CH3->C2H6} $$

Since there are still bromine radicals present, does this newly formed ethane then undergo this reaction?

$$\ce{Br· + C2H6->·C2H5 + HBr} $$

What's to stop this new ethyl radical from continuing this process again? Wouldn't the bromination of methane form secondary products of bromoethane and propane and so on?
How do you ensure, when synthesising a haloalkane through this method, that you only form the haloalkane of the specific chain length you need?

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Bromine radicals will be present in the majority as compared to alkyl radicals and thus making the alkyl chain elongation very less probable, in fact, less and less probable as you increase the number of carbons increased.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar When synthesising on an industrial scale, with thousands of mols of each, wouldn't there be at least a sizeable amount of unwanted bromoethane/propane/butane produced?

Comment: No, much more likely by-product is dibromomethane. Concentration of methyl radical is so small, their reaction with each other is negligible.

Comment: Also bromomethane isn't made like that in practice.